# Interactive Brokers C++ POS API example?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, posix

Has anyone ever seen a working example of this? I am looking for a Linux environment using gcc not Windows with Visual Studio?

The book http://www.interactivebrokers.com/download/GettingStartedC++APIAdvisors.pdf of has:
The C++ API is supported only on Windows, however.

is this Interactive Brokers C++ POS API  still valid or supported?

Thanks

Comment: They provide a dll, so the code will not link. You can try working on windows and run in using wine on linux. But I guess you're looking for performance so you'll have to come up with a different library.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with their C++ API as well.  Might have to turn to these projects instead : 

https://github.com/rudimeier/twstools

https://github.com/rudimeier/twsapi

Answer (score 2):

POSIX API is still supported. Many folks use either https://github.com/rudimeier/twsapi or https://github.com/JanBoonen/TwsApiCpp for their projects since all of the threading, messaging and other housekeeping are taken care of for you.

Answer (score 0):

The TestCppClient project included with the TWS API download can be built on Linux or Mac with the provided makefile. It has macros which detect the OS and include the corresponding appropriate code. 
[TWS API Download](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/)